# Vuetify drawer list item active class

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

** When I click the v-list-item title and icon only navigating the page to corresponding page. when I click on the down arrow it is just opening the list and not navigating to the corresponding page.Can you explain anyone pls? **

```
     <!-- list-items -->
     <v-list-group
         v-for="item in items"
         :key="item.title"
       v-model="item.active"
       active-class="activelistgroup"
       no-action
     >
       <template v-slot:activator >
         <v-list-item :to="item.link" >
           <v-list-item-icon>
             <v-icon v-text="item.action"></v-icon>
           </v-list-item-icon>
           <v-list-item-content >
             <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
           </v-list-item-content>
         </v-list-item>
       </template>

       <v-list-item v-for="child in item.items" :key="child.title">
         <!-- :to="child.link" -->
         <v-list-item-content>
           <v-list-item-title
             class="subtitle"
             v-text="child.title"
           ></v-list-item-title>
         </v-list-item-content>
       </v-list-item>
     </v-list-group>
   </v-list>
 .activelistgroup {
background-color: $appbar-color;

}
.drawer {
background-color: $drawer-color;
width: 300;
}

.v-list--dense .v-list-group--active .v-list-item .v-list-item__title {
color: $font-active;

}
.v-list--dense .v-list-group--active .v-list-item .v-list-item__icon {
color: $font-active;
}
.v-list--dense .v-list-group--active .v-list-item .subtitle {
color: black;
}
.support {
margin-left: 50px;
}
.v-list-item--active a{
padding: 0px;//need to change active class of a
background-color: $appbar-color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<template v-slot:activator>
    <v-list-item :to="item.link">
        <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn icon :to="item.link">
                <v-icon v-text="item.action"></v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
</template>
```

Comment: In my case, i did not relize that <v-list-item> has too many props including the "to" prop which do all the hard work (redirecting and highlighting the current section on the menu). Only one thing, please update or give more references about this solution, maybe will be helpful the fact of explain why do you use that code as correct solution